# Testing for String or other Data Type array using templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates, for-loop, types

I am creating an array template class that needs to be able to handle as broad an input as possible. It will work no problem with int, float, char but I would like to be able to test for strings and other types of arrays so I can sort the main array. I would like the functions to be as generic as possible so it deals with everything the same way.

Essentially, I want to know how to test an unknown variable for its data type in templates.

Comment: If you're writing a general template and want to have the functions as generic as possible, exactly where do you need the template's type information, i.e. why do you need to know the `string` and what are you going to do with it?

Comment: Essentially, if it is a string I want to sort it alphabetically and if it is a number I want to sort by value.

Answer (score 0):

The technique you search for is called "Traits". With a trait you determine the type of a variable by using template specialization.

See http://accu.org/index.php/journals/442 for a good explanation with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in using [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: In case you are using C++0x, TypeTraits are now part of the Standard libs. So you don't need a third party lib for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort your array, just use std::sort. Why do you think you need to treat std::string different from an int? They mostly work the same.